# Phonegap App with cordova, can't install plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, phonegap

So i have this Phonegap app and i need to install the cordova dialogs plugin and, since i'm very noobish in this kinds of things, i just can't get it done.

I tried installing with the "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs" command but i would get a error saying the browser platform was not installed. After a few tries and google searches i managed to "install" the plugin but it still not working.

I can see the plugin on my plugins folder, but on the Phonegap website it says i don't have the dialogs plugin.

I noticed that when i use "cordova plugin" it says i have the dialogs plugin but with "-dev". What does this mean?

I have some prints for you guys to understand better:

https://gyazo.com/e1adb1b2139d9565200b2ece86d63984

https://gyazo.com/85f4e50e962e9a0b0ba3ae978154b882

https://gyazo.com/e318c66edadb3fb11b69956168f275e1

Can you help me please? I'm really stressing out with this and i have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with the build service of phonegap you don't need to use the cordova/phonegap command line.

You just have to manage the config.xml file.

For add you'r plugin just add this to you'r config.xml plugin part file :

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it's working! I did what you said, and some other things i found online and it did work. Thanks a lot man, really appreciated ;)

Comment: you're welcome :) Can you mark this response as satisfactory please :)

Comment: So sorry, i completely forgot it. Done ;)